# Criar uma função de repetição usando dois data frames

Tags: r

Preciso da média de cada variável (x1,x2,x3,x4) de acordo com o mês que ela pertença dados1$mes. O valor dessa média será gravado em (y1,y2,y3,y4) de acordo também com o mês pertencente dados2$mes.
Para x1 será gravado em y1, para x2 em y2 e assim por diante.

Gostaria de uma alternativa mais viável, do que a que fiz abaixo.

```
dados1 <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 30, ncol = 5))
colnames(dados1) <- c("mes","x1","x2","x3","x4")

dados1$mes <- c(5,9,7,3,8,2,4,1,6,10,2,11,12,10,12,2,8,9,10,7,6,4,5,7,3,1,9,5,2,6)
dados1$x1 <- c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58,60)
dados1$x2 <- c(3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90)
dados1$x3 <- c(4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64,68,72,76,80,84,88,92,96,100,104,108,112,116,120)
dados1$x4 <- c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,105,110,115,120,125,130,135,140,145,150)

dados2 <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = 12, ncol = 5))
colnames(dados2) <- c("mes","y1","y2","y3","y4")
dados2$mes <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
```

Criei os contadores para todos os meses:

```
contador_dias_jan <- 0
somatorio_jan <- 0
contador_dias_fev <- 0
somatorio_fev <- 0
contador_dias_mar <- 0
somatorio_mar <- 0
contador_dias_abr <- 0
somatorio_abr <- 0
contador_dias_mai <- 0
somatorio_mai <- 0
contador_dias_jun <- 0
somatorio_jun <- 0
contador_dias_jul <- 0
somatorio_jul <- 0
contador_dias_ago <- 0
somatorio_ago <- 0
contador_dias_set <- 0
somatorio_set <- 0
contador_dias_out <- 0
somatorio_out <- 0
contador_dias_nov <- 0
somatorio_nov <- 0
contador_dias_dez <- 0
somatorio_dez <- 0
```

Aqui esta somente para janeiro e fevereiro, mas teria o "if else" até dezembro.

```
for (L in 1:30) {
  #para janeiro
  if (dados1$mes[L] == 1) {
    contador_dias_jan <- contador_dias_jan + 1
    somatorio_jan <- somatorio_jan + dados1$x1[L]
    #para fevereiro
  } if else (dados1$mes[L] == 2) {
    contador_dias_fev <- contador_dias_fev + 1
    somatorio_fev <- somatorio_fev + dados1$x1[L]
  }
}

for (L in 1:12) {
  #para janeiro
  if (L == 1) {
    dados2$y1[L] <- somatorio_jan / contador_dias_jan
    #para fevereiro
  } else if (L == 2) {
    dados2$y1[L] <- somatorio_fev / contador_dias_fev
  }
}
```

Da forma que está, seria somente para preencher y1. Falta ainda y2, y3 e y4. Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De maneira geral, não é nem necessário nem recomendável usar loops em R; a família `apply` é mais eficiente. No caso de operações por grupo, combine com o uso de `split`:

```
# Separa os dados por mês
dadosL <- split(dados1, dados1$mes)

# Calcula as médias por colunas para todos os elementos da lista:
dadosM <- lapply(dadosL, colMeans)

# Une os elementos da lista de volta em um único data.frame
dadosF <- do.call("rbind", dadosM)

head(dadosF, 4)
#>   mes x1   x2 x3   x4
#> 1   1 34 51.0 68 85.0
#> 2   2 31 46.5 62 77.5
#> 3   3 29 43.5 58 72.5
#> 4   4 29 43.5 58 72.5
```

Os pacotes dplyr e data.table automatizam operações do tipo split/apply:

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

dados1 %>%
  group_by(mes) %>%
  summarise_all(mean)
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dados1) # estabelece dados1 como classe data.table

dados1[, lapply(.SD, mean), mes]
```

Comment: Obrigada pela orientação @Carlos Eduardo Lagosta. Me auxiliou muito! Irei buscar mais por esses pacotes utilizados em sua resposta.